# Spring boot application for background workers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, backgroundworker, runnable

I have defined the following Spring boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).web(WebApplicationType.NONE).run(args);
    }

    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Thread.currentThread().join();
    }
}
```

I also have a package of workers (i.e. could be classes which implements `Runnable`). They are supposed to run indefinitely.

What is the "Spring way" to run them? (and doing so automatically, without explicitly knowing them)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could (1) have your classes that implement Runnable be annotated with @Component, so that Spring can find them.  You can then (2) write a WorkManager, annotated with @Service, with an @Autowired List - which Spring would initialize with a list instances of all your classes from (1).  And could (3) write a @PostConstruct method in your WorkManager that would iterate over that list of Runnables, and pass each one to a TaskExecutor to run...

Comment: each one of the options sound good to me. Suppose I'm choosing options #1. How do I run them? for option #2: How do you AutoWire the list so it will be populated with all the workers? and the same for #3: how do you iterate them? (I'm relatively new to spring boot)

Comment: Hi!  Sorry - I meant you have to implement all three of these together...  Step (3) is the one that will run them all (giv them to the task executor to run. Step (2) is the one that will put them in a list for you - Spring will do that during context init.  Step (1) is needed to it knows what to pay attention to.

Answer (score 4):

> and doing so automatically, without explicitly knowing them

There's no mechanism to automatically run some `Runnable`s from a certain place. You need to find a way to inform Spring about these classes.

Three common scenarios:

1. Execute some code during the application startup: [`ApplicationRunner`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ApplicationRunner.html) and [`CommandLineRunner`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner.html).

You either congregate `Runnable`s and wrap them up into an `[Application|CommandLine]Runner` which should be a bean (e.g. `@Bean`, `@Component`, etc) or make each `Runnable` a separate `[Application|CommandLine]Runner`.

2. Execute some code at some point of time: [`TaskExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/TaskExecutor.html).

You inject a `TaskExecutor` and give it previously gathered `Runnable`s.

3. Execute some code repeatedly: [`TaskScheduler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html).

You inject a `TaskScheduler` and give it previously gathered `Runnable`s, plus [a trigger](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling-trigger-implementations).

More details: [Task Execution and Scheduling](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling)

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I don't have a problem making those classes as `@Component` (sorry if that was misunderstood). Suppose I've done this. I know that spring will scan and identify them for me. The question is, how to run them all?