# Spring boot application interacting with indipendent workers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application that serves requests from client (Angular). Now, I want to make this application a little bit more efficient, distributing some kind of jobs between many workers with a "task queue" style. So, basically, the client sends a request for a task, the Spring core creates multiple messages (based on weight of the task) and deliver them to workers through a queue. The workers (of course) always listen for new messages.

[image]

Now, my problem is that workers and core should share some dependencies for persistency (Spring Data, models classes and so on). A good solution has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53363433/spring-boot-application-for-background-workers), but in this way the workers are closely dipendent on core.
I want the workers to be "indipendent" from the core, in the sense that I would instantiate or remove as many workers as I need, wheneven, whitout restarting application or other tricks.

So, my question is, how to create indipendent runnable workers that share some dependencies with the core? What is the best design solution in your opinion?

Comment: Why don't you like the reference solution?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli  in that case the workers should be initialized a priori, and the number will remain the same until the app will be restarted. I want the workers indipendent, I want to increase and decrease the number of workers even runtime

Comment: You can reconfigure the TaskExecutor. On what platform are you running your application?

Comment: At the moment there is no platform, I'm testing on my local (Windows). Why? And how can I reconfigure the TaskExecutor?

Comment: So if you do that just for testing, why do you think that you will have this requirement? On the other hand why don't you search on google?

Comment: It is for testing just for now, I'm going to deploy it. Thank you for your answer, very clear and kind !